# Problems with mysql syntax

Tags: sql, mysql, triggers, mysql-error-1064

I´m trying to create a trigger on MySQL but I´m having a syntax problem, which I was not able to find. If someone more experience could help me it would be great (it´s the first time I use MySQL!)...

The reason why I´m creating this trigger is for deleting all the orphan "labels", which has a many-to-many relation with "service_descriptor" (this two entities are linked by service_labels).

The code I have is:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `trg_delete_orphan_label` AFTER DELETE 
FOR EACH ROW ON `restdb`.`service_labels`  
  DELETE FROM `restdb`.`labels`
   WHERE EXISTS (SELECT *
                   FROM old D 
              LEFT_JOIN `restdb`.`service_labels` SL ON SL.`id_label` = D.`id_label` 
                                                    AND D.`id_service` = SL.`id_service`
                  WHERE SL.`id_label` IS NULL
                        `restdb`.`labels`.`id` = D.SL.`id_label`);
```

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone ... I´ve finaly solved it because of your help...

In the end the work is:

CREATE TRIGGER `trg_delete_orphan_label` AFTER DELETE ON `restdb`.`service_descriptor`
FOR EACH ROW 
    DELETE  FROM `restdb`.`labels` 
    WHERE `id` NOT IN ( 
        SELECT `restdb`.`service_labels`.`id_label` 
        FROM `restdb`.`service_labels` );

Comment: I'm glad you found something that works, although I notice that the trigger is on a different table now. Your solution is slightly different from mine both functionally and from a performance standpoint. Your trigger is deleting ALL orphans, whereas mine only deletes newly orphaned rows. My approach will also be faster, so you may want to consider it.

Comment: Yes! It's truth... the problem is that it didn't work when the trigger was on service_labels table, even though the deleting statement works well for the orphan ones... it's because the service_labes table was not being deleted directly... it was being deleted by cacade after service_descriptor...
For that reason I've changed the table and because of that I had to change the logic as well!

Answer (score 1):

You have missed AND

Try this code

```
CREATE TRIGGER `trg_delete_orphan_label` AFTER DELETE FOR EACH ROW ON `restdb`.`service_labels`   
    DELETE 
    FROM 
        `restdb`.`labels` 
    WHERE 
        EXISTS (SELECT 
                    * 
                FROM 
                    old D LEFT_JOIN 
                    `restdb`.`service_labels` SL ON 
                        SL.`id_label` = D.`id_label` AND 
                        D.`id_service` = SL.`id_service` 
                WHERE 
                    SL.`id_label` IS NULL AND
                    `restdb`.`labels`.`id` = D.SL.`id_label`                         
                    );
```

Comment: I´ve added an and. It still with some syntax problem, though...

Thanks for your support !

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of problems with your trigger, most notably the placement of "FOR EACH ROW", and the way you are treating OLD like a table, when it's really just a row.

This should work for you:

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `trg_delete_orphan_label`;

CREATE TRIGGER `trg_delete_orphan_label` AFTER DELETE ON `service_labels` 
FOR EACH ROW
    DELETE FROM `labels`
    WHERE `id` = OLD.`id_label`
    AND NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT NULL
        FROM `service_labels` SL 
        WHERE SL.`id_label` = `labels`.`id`                        
    );
```